# How to get sorted list of apps, for a developer, from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to be able to direct users of my apps to the Google Play store to see other apps I have developed.

Here is the link I have been trying so far, but the following issues are happening...

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=horseboxsoftware&c=apps&price=1

1. Two apps are showing up that are not mine.
2. The apps are not sorted in alphabetical order
3. Not all of my apps are being returned.

Any idea how to get a complete, sorted list of my own apps?

Answer (score 2):

If you want only your apps to show, use this query: https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Horsebox+Software. I don't know if you can sort them by name.

Answer (score 0):

> https://play.google.com/store/search?q=horseboxsoftware&c=apps&price=1

You sort by price. Make query more geneic:

```
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=horseboxsoftware
```

and it should sort by name. As for:

```
Two apps are showing up that are not mine.
```

Then basically you need to either live with it, or make your query "horseboxsoftware' hitting just you (which most likely editing your name to be more unique as apparently `horseboxsoftware` is not only yours idea.